# Unable to redirect to CAS for single log out from spring

Tags: spring-security, logout, cas

I am developing an application which has an angular2 frontend and a spring boot backend. For the authentication I am using CAS. Single sign on is working properly, but the single log out is not working and not even redirecting to cas/logout endpoint.(I am sending a POST to my spring boot app's /logout url from angular app )

CAS version - 4.2.2

CAS client core - 3.4

I followed http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-filter-urls-cas and did necessary changes to Authentication Filter and Logout filter. But still I couldn't identify the issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private AuthProperties properties;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(requestSingleLogoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(casAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("//**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
        .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    }

    /***
     * Service Properties refer to the application which is being authenticated
     * Typically in this case, the service is the authentication engine or auth app
     */
    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties sp = new ServiceProperties();
        sp.setService(properties.getAppServiceSecurity());
        sp.setArtifactParameter("casTicket");
        sp.setAuthenticateAllArtifacts(true);
        sp.setSendRenew(false);
        return sp;
    }
    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(userService());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        if (properties.isCasProxyTicket()) {
            casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas30ServiceProxyTicketValidator());
            casAuthenticationProvider.setStatelessTicketCache(ehManager());
        } else {
            casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas30ServiceTicketValidator());
        }

        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey(properties.getProviderKey());
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionStrategy() {
        SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionStrategy = new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
        return sessionStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cas30ServiceTicketValidator cas30ServiceTicketValidator() {
        return new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator(properties.getCasUrlPrefix());
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionStrategy());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setProxyGrantingTicketStorage(pgtStorage());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login/cas");
        casAuthenticationFilter.setProxyReceptorUrl(properties.getCasProxyReceptor());
        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new TBXCasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(properties.getCasLoginUrl());
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }


    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter requestSingleLogoutFilter() {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        stringBuffer.append(properties.getCasLogoutUrl());
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("https://localhost:9443/cas/logout", new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());//env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_LOGOUT) + "?service="+ env.getRequiredProperty(APP_SERVICE_HOME)
        logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout");
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
        SingleSignOutFilter filter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
        filter.setArtifactParameterName(Protocol.CAS3.getArtifactParameterName());
        filter.setCasServerUrlPrefix("https://localhost:9443/cas");
        filter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
        return filter;
    }


    @Bean
    public Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    if (cookie != null) {
                    } else {
                    }
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }



    /**
     * configure via WebSecurity provides the fonts, images, scripts, styles and views to be removed
     * from the security features, because, access to these scripts is a must regarding the user experience
     **/
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/fonts*//**")
                .antMatchers("/images1*//**")
                .antMatchers("/scripts*//**")
                .antMatchers("/styles*//**")
                .antMatchers("/views*//**")
                .antMatchers("/i18n*//**");
    }
    @Bean
    public UserPrincipleHandler userService() {
        UserPrincipleHandler userPrincipleServiceHanlder = new UserPrincipleHandler();
        return userPrincipleServiceHanlder;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
        return new RequestContextFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource serviceAuthenticationDataSource() {
        ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource serviceDetailSource = new ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource(serviceProperties());
        return serviceDetailSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthentication() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl(properties.getCasFailureUrl());
        return failureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyList proxyChainList() {
        List<String> list = properties.getProxyList();
        String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(), list.size(), String[].class);
        List<String[]> urls = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        urls.add(stringArray);
        ProxyList proxyList = new ProxyList(urls);
        return proxyList;
    }


    @Bean
    public ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl pgtStorage() {
        ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl pgtImpl = new ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl();
        return pgtImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringCacheBasedTicketCache ehManager() throws Exception {
        SpringCacheBasedTicketCache ehmanager = new SpringCacheBasedTicketCache(cacheMap());
        return ehmanager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMapCache cacheMap() {
        ConcurrentMapCache conCacheMap = new ConcurrentMapCache("casTickets");
        conCacheMap.put("casTickets", 50);
        return conCacheMap;
    }
    @Bean
    public Cas30ProxyTicketValidator cas30ServiceProxyTicketValidator() {

        Cas30ProxyTicketValidator validator = new Cas30ProxyTicketValidator(properties.getCasUrlPrefix());//env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_PREFIX)
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        stringBuffer.append(properties.getAppServiceHome()).append(properties.getCasProxyReceptor());
        validator.setProxyCallbackUrl(stringBuffer.toString());//env.getRequiredProperty(APP_SERVICE_HOME)+"login/cas/proxyreceptor"
        validator.setProxyGrantingTicketStorage(pgtStorage());
        validator.setAllowedProxyChains(proxyChainList());
        validator.setAcceptAnyProxy(false);

        return validator;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to implement this with angular2?

Comment: Yeah managed to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you share how did you solve the problem? do you have an example or repo for this project?